# How config bot for availably for only channel

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

I would like the application, when called via the chat bar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bb5i.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV2g1.png)

to first check whether the user is in "groupChat" or in "channel". If in "groupChat", it should display a card with the information "Channel Only". If in "channel", it should show the other options available, i.e. a search query and the possibility to create a card.... how to do this?

I've tried config manifest.json in appPackage:

```
...more code
"bots": [
            {
            "botId": "${{BOT_ID}}",
        "scopes": ["team"],
        "supportsFiles": false,
        "isNotificationOnly": false,
        "commandLists": [
            {
                "scopes": ["team"],
                "commands": [
                    {
                            "title": "welcome",
                        "description": "Resend welcome card of this Bot"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "learn",
                        "description": "Learn about Adaptive Card and Bot Command"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
.... more code
```

and too add code in index.js:

```js
server.post('/api/messages', async (req, res) => {
    await adapter.process(req, res, async context => {
        const conversationType = context.activity.conversation.conversationType

        if (conversationType === 'groupChat') {
            const card = cardTools.AdaptiveCards.declareWithoutData(rawOnlyChannel).render()
            await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)] })
        } else if (conversationType === 'channel') {
            await bot.run(context)
        } else {
            await context.sendActivity('Unknown type of conversation')
        }
    })
})
```

and I create new card in folder adaptiveCards:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.4",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "No authority",
            "wrap": true,
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "size": "Large",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "color": "Attention"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Operation only available on channels",
            "wrap": true,
            "fontType": "Default",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "color": "Warning"
        }
    ],
    "verticalContentAlignment": "Center"
}
```

but not only do I get such errors in the console:

```
[onTurnError] unhandled error: Error: The bot is not part of the conversation roster.
RestError: The bot is not part of the conversation roster.
    at new RestError (D:\...\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:2479:28)
    at D:\...\bot\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:3644:37
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'BotNotInConversationRoster',
  statusCode: 403,
  request: WebResource {
    streamResponseBody: false,
    url: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/19%3A7990a50d-8507-4843-967c-c85c7bbbada2_8d058514-b4c4-415b-bf87-346bfcbaf116%40unq.gbl.spaces/activities/f%3A0711bd76-0c16-608b-ab24-b788a8fd0a31',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
    body: '{"type":"message","serviceUrl":"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/","channelId":"msteams","from":{"id":"28:2a7dc32d-240a-4a73-bfe3-01bb14a08089","name":"..."},"conversation":{"isGroup":true,"conversationType":"groupChat","id":"...","tenantId":"..."},"recipient":{"id":"...","name":"...","aadObjectId":"..."},"locale":"...","text":"The bot encountered an unhandled error:\\n The bot is not part of the conversation roster.","inputHint":"acceptingInput","replyToId":"f:0711bd76-0c16-608b-ab24-b788a8fd0a31"}',
    query: undefined,
    formData: undefined,
    withCredentials: false,
    abortSignal: undefined,
    timeout: 0,
    onUploadProgress: undefined,
    onDownloadProgress: undefined,
    proxySettings: undefined,
    keepAlive: undefined,
    agentSettings: undefined,
    redirectLimit: undefined,
    operationSpec: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      path: 'v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId}',
      urlParameters: [Array],
      headerParameters: [Array],
      requestBody: [Object],
      responses: [Object],
      serializer: [Serializer]
    }
  },
  response: {
    body: '{"error":{"code":"BotNotInConversationRoster","message":"The bot is not part of the conversation roster."}}',
    headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
    status: 403
  },
  body: {
    error: {
      code: 'BotNotInConversationRoster',
      message: 'The bot is not part of the conversation roster.'
    }
  }
}
```

this additionally does not run as I intended, the bot only checks after the user action of selecting a tab or searching.

I create app by using toolit teams in vs code. I'm using: Bot, Personal App and Messaging extension

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now and can't come to a solution, so I'm asking for some guidance on what I'm doing wrong and how I can configure the app correctly so that before running the commandId check it first checks before the user interaction to see if they are in the channel....

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: Look like duplicate of this thread, Please Track this issue from here.
-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1397597/problem-with-configuring-a-channel-only-bot-when-u?orderby=helpful#answers